# Переформатировать дату полученную из БД в формат где месяцы считаются с 0 до 11

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Подскажите, как переформатировать дату полученную из БД mysql (а она в формате YYYY-MM-DD и месяца считаются с 1-12) в дату на JS, где я в конструкторе формирую тот же формат (YYYY-MM-DD), но на JS месяцы считаются с 0 до 11.

Хотелось бы идею реализации на стороне сервера (PHP), но на худой конец на JS тоже пойдет.

`today_date` - это new Date в JS
`task_list` - это массив данных из БД (task.date это поле с датой из БД)

```
function todoContent(task_list, today_date){

        clearTaskList.call(document.querySelector('.hard_task'));
        clearTaskList.call(document.querySelector('.flexible_task'));
        //если есть задачи

        task_list.forEach(function(task){
            if(task.date == today_date){

                if(task.time !== null){
                    listTask.call(document.querySelector('.hard_task'), task);
                }else{
                    listTask.call(document.querySelector('.flexible_task'), task);
                }//end els
            }
        });
}//end todoContent////////////
```

Comment: вы ее в таймштамп переведите и форматировать не придется ничего

Comment: перевел но все равно не понимаю как сравнить, дата в js имеет вид Sat Oct 13 2018 16:09:28 GMT+0700 (Новосибирск, стандартное время) а timestamp 2018-10-16 00:00:00

Comment: добавьте  код, что и как вы делаете

Comment: `function todoContent(task_list, today_date){

  clearTaskList.call(document.querySelector('.hard_task'));
  clearTaskList.call(document.querySelector('.flexible_task'));
  //если есть задачи
  
  task_list.forEach(function(task){
   if(task.date == today_date){
    
    if(task.time !== null){
     listTask.call(document.querySelector('.hard_task'), task);
    }else{
     listTask.call(document.querySelector('.flexible_task'), task);
    }//end els
   }
  });
}//end todoContent////////////`

Comment: today_date  - это new Date  в JS

Comment: task_list - это массив данных из бд (task.date  это поле с датой из бд

Comment: воспользуйтесь [edit] чтобы изменить вопрос. код в комментариях не читаем

Comment: ок, добавил код выше

Comment: только дошло, таймстамп это функция такая? а я в бд смотрю. вот только все равно не понял как этой функцийй воспользоваться

Comment: в sql выбираете не `dateField` а `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateField) as ts` получаете значение в секундах, а js передаете его умноженным на тысячу в конструктор даты. `var d = new Date($ts * 1000)`. могут  правда быть нюансы с часовым поясом.

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал задачу следующим образом - обработал даты в модели на php, убрал нули и сравнял числа js и php

```
function dateToJs($res){
        //переводим дату из MYSQL формата  в JavaScript формат
        for($i = 0; $i < count($res); $i++){

            $date = explode('-', $res[$i]['date']);

            if($date[1] < 10){
                $date[1] = substr($date[1], 1); 
            }
            if($date[2] < 10){
                $date[2] = substr($date[2], 1); 
            }
            $date[1] = $date[1] - 1;

            $res[$i]['date'] = implode('-', $date);
        };
        return $res;
    };//end dateToJs
```